# Wait for AsyncTask.execute(()) to finish before returning result

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-room

I am reading data from local `Android RoomDB` and I need to do it in background because well reading from `DB` is not allowed on `UI Thread`. So I have this method:

```
@Override
public DBBackedRouteModel getDBBackedRouteModelByID(Long id) {
    AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
        this.dbBackedRouteModel = routesParser.getDBBackedRouteModel(id);
    });
    return dbBackedRouteModel;
}
```

Is there a way to know that the `Async` has finished and return the result only then?

Comment: i think you need to implement onPostExecute() method AsyncTask<>. onPostExecute only called when your process is done

Answer (score 0):

You can use [callbacks](https://javascript.info/callbacks). I am not sure what you want to do exactly but you could, for example, do a console log when the Async is finished.

Comment: Well I am trying to return `dbBackedRouteModel` in this case but with the current code it will return `null` since it returns it before the `ASyncTask` is complete

Comment: I am not too sure since I haven't faced something similar before but [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus. onPostExecute() method of async task you can post the event and pass the value which you want to read.
Hope this will solve your problem